# Computation error

Tags: java

I've been having trouble with my program. Im supposed to take in 3 variables and plug them into a formula to get an answer. My answer comes out to 0.0 and im not sure what i am doing wrong.

```
public double compute_cert (int years, double amount, double rate, double certificate)
{
    certificate = amount * Math.pow(1 + rate/100, years);
    return certificate;
}
```

The variables rate, amount and years are set up correctly but the answer certificate is always returned as 0.0

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int years = 0;
    double amount = 0;
    double rate = 0;
    double certificate = 0;
    char ans;// allows for char 

    do{
        CDProgram C = new CDProgram(years, amount, rate, certificate);
        C.get_years();
        C.get_amount();
        C.get_rate();
        C.get_info();
        C.compute_cert(years, amount, rate, certificate);
        System.out.println ("Would you like to repeat this program? (Y/N)");
        ans = console.next().charAt(0);// user enters either Y or y until they wish to exit the program
   } while(ans == 'Y'||ans == 'y'); // test of do/while loop

}
```

Not sure what else to do. Thanks for the help

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - `rate` is a double, and a double divided by an integer gives a double.  So the difference between 100 and 100.0 is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: @DavidWallace: you're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `CDProgram` class has fields for `years`, `amount` and `rate`, and your `get_` method are prompting the user for the values.

That being the case, it doesn't make sense to pass parameters for them into your calculation method.  I would change the method to this.

```
public double compute_cert () {
    certificate = amount * Math.pow(1 + rate/100, years);
    return certificate;
}
```

Then when you call it in `main`, don't pass any values in.  This will just use the values from the fields in the `CDProgram` class.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not assigning the local variables that you are passing into the computation function?

```
   years = C.get_years();
   amount = C.get_amount();
   rate = C.get_rate();
   info = C.get_info();
```

As it is, the code is just passing `0` for every parameter into your function. Multiplying by `0` will get you `0`.  If you pass `0`, the following line will multiply `0` by some quantity.

```
certificate = amount * Math.pow(1 + rate/100, years);
```

Comment: Just a little addition: Search for pass-by-value/pass-by-reference for more information

Comment: I get those variables to return with some value which means that they should be plugged into the equation with 0 when i call the math function. I used this method and did the same with the variable certificate and still no luck.

Comment: @NJD, At the time that you are making your call to `compute_cert`, if you pass it `0` for every parameter, it will use `0`, because local variables (function arguments in this case) always shadow any global variables with the same name.